# Set values in arrayList with loop

Tags: java

```
 ArrayList<Rectangle> list = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
  for (int i=0; i < 10; i++)
  {
  list.add(new Rectangle(10,20));

  }

 for (int i=0; i < list.size(); i++ )
  {
     Rectangle rec = list.get(i);
     System.out.print("Element " + i +"  ");
     System.out.println("x=" + rec.getX()+"   y=" + rec.getY());
  }
```

This output gives me:

```
  Element 0  x=0.0   y=0.0
  Element 1  x=0.0   y=0.0
  Element 2  x=0.0   y=0.0
  Element 3  x=0.0   y=0.0
  Element 4  x=0.0   y=0.0
  Element 5  x=0.0   y=0.0
  Element 6  x=0.0   y=0.0
  Element 7  x=0.0   y=0.0
  Element 8  x=0.0   y=0.0
  Element 9  x=0.0   y=0.0
```

I would like to make 10 elements with values 0f 10 and 20 each.

Comment: Without the code for `Rectangle` it is difficult to see what is going wrong. Can you include this too?

Comment: what should be 10 and 20 ? The top left corner ? Then you have to use the constructor taking four integers. In the version you have posted you're just initializing a rectangle's width and height, leaving the top left corner at 0,0.

Comment: @sgmorrison - Rectangle is part of Java libraries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [constructor that gets two arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#Rectangle%28int,%20int%29) is this:

```
Rectangle(int width, int height)
```

Which doesn't set x and y.

You can either use this constructor:

```
Rectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height)
```

E.g.

```
list.add(new Rectangle(10,20,0,0));
```

Or set x and y after creating the object:

```
for (int i=0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
    rect.setLocation(10, 20);
    list.add(rect);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [Rectangle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#Rectangle%28int,%20int%29) constructor that you're using takes a width and a height. You're not setting the x and y values.